# visual workflow- How to create multiple records using visual workflow

Tags: visual-workflow

I am completely new to Visual Workflows. I want to add a button on the Account detail page and on-clicking the Button the user should be able to create three records (One account, One contact and one Asset Record). Is there any example that i can use to work on this issue. Right-now i'm not able to figure out where to start.

Thank you

Comment: This is right time to learn flow, refer this trailhead "Collect Information from Users and then Operate on It with Visual Workflow" https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/business_process_automation/units/flow

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, but with limited information it is difficult to give you the right answer.

The button will be a url something like

```
flow/NameofMyFlow?varinmyflow={!Account.Id}&retURL={!Account.Id}&saveURL={!Opportunity.Id}
```

varinmyflow is a variable you set in your flow, assuming you need account variables to be passed from the account you are on to the flow creating the new records.

To create one record on one object, you will use record create. If you are creating multiple records on one object you use fast create. Fast is for lists.

I recommend the site below as it is the best resource I have found for visual workflows.

https://salesforcesidekick.com/2015/05/09/how-to-use-a-record-create/

This is not my site, but it has the best information on this topic I have found.

Comment: I chose not to upvote your answer because there is enough information in the question to give the user a detailed explanation of what to do and your answer says "with limited information..." which seems to imply you didn't actually understand the question. Otherwise, there's plenty of useful info in your answer.